# Get Graph API valid access token from Sharepoint Online login

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

actually I have to publish a custom full page on Sharepoint Online (not using modern pages buy just a simple aspx) and call Graph API via javascript.

To do that, I need an access token, but I don't know how to get it from the Sharepoint login session. I have noticed that there are many variables in the session after login, with various tokens, but none of them is good for calling graph apis

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class called `MSGraphClient` to connect to Microsoft Graph.

An example here.

```
export default class HelloWorldWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWorldWebPartProps> {
  public render(): void {
    // ...

    this.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
        // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
        client
          .api('/me')
          .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
            // handle the response
        });
      });
  }

  // ...
}
```

See references from [Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph) and [Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial).